# Which approach is better to load a JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc

There are two ways to load a driver:

1. `Class.forName()`
2. `DriverManager.registerDriver()`

Method 1 internally also calls DriverManager.registerDriver and method 1 is the preferred way.

But why? Is there any small difference or is performance etc. better?
Any views are appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Class.forName(), then you are not required to have any compile-time dependencies on a particular JDBC driver.  This is particularly useful when you are writing code that can work with a variety of databases.

Consider the following code:

```
// Register the PostgreSQL driver
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Now compare it to:

```
import org.postgresql.Driver;

// Register the PostgreSQL driver
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
```

And consider that in the first example, the class name could also have come from a properties file, XML file, etc., depending on what's convenient for your application.

Answer (score 2):

The [JDBC API Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321173848) is the best reference for such questions, a [section of which addresses the role played by the Driver and DriverManager classes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/drivermanager.html).

**All Driver classes are expected to have a static initializer that is responsible for creating an instance of that Driver, and register it with the DriverManager, when the Driver class is loaded.**

Additionally, the DriverManager.getConnection() is probably the only user-space friendly method in the class. Most of the other methods are usually not used by most developers using the JDBC API. So the old adage still stands - use Class.forName() to load the driver, and then use DriverManager.getConnection() to get a connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) it looks like Class.forName was required to start with, and then things changed so that it was no longer the prefered way (or the required way).

Comment: fixed, thanks (I was reading up on what it was saying and I guess I forgot to re-grab the link :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, your life will be much easier if you construct a driver instance by statically reference the driver. Once you have that, you can ignore `DriverManager` which made of evil.

Answer (score 1):

"is performance etc. better?"

I would say that performance for this one-time operation is the least of your worries.

If you're using a Java EE app server the answer is "neither".  You should be setting up a connection pool and let it handle loading the driver and handing out the connections.